# Valence, Variable Valence, and Valency

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, valence

As per the latest [IUPAC Compendium of Chemical Terminology](https://goldbook.iupac.org/), informally known as the "**Gold Book**", the terms **valency** or **variable valence** are not defined; however, [**valence**](https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/V06588) is defined as:

> The *maximum* number of univalent atoms (originally hydrogen or
> chlorine atoms) that may combine with an atom of the element under
> consideration, or with a fragment, or for which an atom of this
> element can be substituted.

This definition was published in the article *Glossary of Terms Used in Physical Organic Chemistry: IUPAC Recommendations 1994*$^1$ by Muller, P., Chairman, The Commission of on Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry, Organic Chemistry Devision, IUPAC during the preparation of these recommendations (1987, 1993).

This [glossary of terms](https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/) is also available online. According to this definition, **valence** should be a fixed number.

However, lambda ($\lambda$) nomenclature for **variable valence** was developed in the article *Treatment of Variable Valence in Organic Nomenclature (Lambda Convention): Recommendations 1983*$^2$ by Powell, W. H., Associate Member, The Commission of on Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry, Organic Chemistry Devision, IUPAC during the preparation of these recommendations (1975, 1983).

I have many questions regarding this:

1. Has the concept of variable valence been discarded from the IUPAC recommendations for organic nomenclature between 1983 and 1994?
2. Is the nomenclature different for physical organic chemistry and organic chemistry?
3. Is the $\lambda$ nomenclature valid anymore?

#### References

1. *Glossary of Terms Used in Physical Organic Chemistry: IUPAC Recommendations 1994.* Muller, P. [10.1351/pac199466051077](https://doi.org/10.1351/pac199466051077)
2. *Variable Valence in Organic Nomenclature (Lambda Convention): Recommendations 1983*, Powell, W. [10.1351/pac198456060769](https://doi.org/10.1351/pac198456060769)

Comment: If valence is fixed (it totally is according to the definition we use), it can't be variable. However, valence isn't a useful concept (it never was). But that makes variable valence also no useful concept. And nomenclature is not the same as a chemical concept. The constant struggle about people saying one thing while meaning another.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン in certain cases valence does prove useful: carbon forms a maximum of four bonds.

Comment: First define what a bond is, then see whether that fits valency. There are examples where carbon is bonded to 5 partners. With this example alone, the concept has lost all meaning.